# Django pre_save signal: how do I know if it is Insert or Update

Tags: python, django, signals

I'm working in a pre_save signal of a model and I don't know how to check if the record is a INSERT or UPDATE. Code below (doesn't work properly):

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Person)
def pre_save_person(sender, instance, **kwargs): 

    if not instance.pk:
        print 'INSERT !!!!!!'
    else:
        print 'UPDATE !!!!!!'
```

Can you help me? The project uses django 1.8.7.

Thanks for any help

Comment: That would work, except that the if conditions are the wrong way round.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, I saw the if condition was wrong. But It doesn't work anyway. Instance.pk always exist

Comment: If the pk exists, then Django doesn't know either if it's an update or an insert. In that case, Django will try an update, and if that fails fall back to an insert. If your application sets the pk before the instance is saved, you can only find out for sure by querying the db for a matching pk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following @ knbk comment, the instance.pk will always exist at this point. You must check if this instance.pk exists in database:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Person)
def pre_save_person(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    num = Person.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).count()
    if num == 0 :
        print 'INSERT !!'
    else:
        print 'UPDATE !!'
```

Comment: This leads to an additional database query. It's true that retrieving a single item based on primary key is extremely fast , but still it's better to avoid an extra query whenever possible.

Comment: @e4c5 Good tip and I was thinking the same thing. How would you avoid an extra query in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

`if instance.pk is None: 
     print "inserting"
 else:
     print "updating"`

this wont work in all cases , I recommend using [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save)  where you have the flag created unless you specifically need pre_save

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work, instance.pk is always there and I can't use post because I'm creating a record of a related model

Answer (score 0):

You can check it in a simple way

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Person)
def pre_save_person(sender, instance, **kwargs): 
    try:
        Person.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        print("inserting")
    except Person.DoesNotExist:
        print("updating")
```